# stored procedure takes long time to execute than queries

Tags: mysql

I've made a normal query which returns 19800 records within 0.0004 seconds when I execute it as query.

When I put that query in a procedure it takes too much time to execute.

My stored procedure has no parameters.

**My Query is:**

```
SELECT s.name FROM student AS s, test AS t WHERE t.id = 1 AND s.testid = t.id;
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Where you say: `When I put that query in a procedure` ... does this mean the ***same exact*** query?  Also, what does: `takes too much time to execute` mean? We might also need to see the structure (add it to the bottom of the question) of your `student` table.

Comment: @Paul T.. Yes sir same exact query. Sir student table contains basic student information nothing else and all columns have indexing.

Comment: Ok, what about the other question and the table structure?

Comment: @Paul T. When I set that query into stored procedure, procedure takes long time to return query result. Table structure is:  `id` bigint, `userid` text, `password` text, `name` text, `registrationdate` datetime, `email` text, `mobileno` bigint, `address` text, `testid` bigint, `course` text

Comment: Again you say: `takes a long time`, but what does "too much", or "long time" mean to you ... 2 seconds?, 2 minutes? ... how long does the query take from the procedure?

Comment: ... see my previous comment too. Anyway, try to avoid `WHERE-clause-joins`. Try this query instead: `SELECT s.name FROM student s INNER JOIN test t ON s.testid = t.id WHERE t.id = 1`. Also, know that "indexing all columns" is generally a bad idea, and can lead to other issues.

Comment: @Paul T. phpmyadmin displays Fatal Error: time exceed 300 sec..., rather than I'm not able to show query result